# django Pycharm 2020.2.2 not resolving static files when using "pathlib.Path" to address BASE_DIR

Tags: django, pycharm, django-staticfiles

I'm using the latest version of Pycharm, **2020.2.2** and django 3.1.

In my project, I removed the default `settings.py` and created a directory named `settings`, so the whole project root looks like:

```
tsetmc
├── asgi.py
├── celery.py
├── context_processors.py
├── __init__.py
├── settings
│   ├── base.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── local.py
├── urls.py
├── views.py
└── wsgi.py
```

and in the `base.py`, I defined the static files setting as:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent.parent

...

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'assets/'
]

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'staticfiles/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media/'
```

Everything works fine *in the browser* and the static files are successfully loaded using the `{% static %}` tag; However, Pycharm can not resolve any of the static files in the templates.

**I enabled Django Support, set `Django project root` and `settings` in the Pycharm settings accordingly and also set the `Template Language` as Django; but it didn't solve the issue.**

---

After some trial-and-error, I found an odd solution; If I use `import os` and `os.path.join()` to locate the static paths, instead of `from pathlib import Path` and `/`, Pycharm can resolve the static files without any problem.

So when I changed my `base.py` to look like this:

```
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))


STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets')
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/')
```

(after invalidating the cache, without changing any other configuration)

Pycahrm can fully resolve the static files.

*What am I missing here?* Is there any problem with using `Path` to address the static files? or the problem is about the Pycharm itself?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known limitation of PyCharm, you can see this 6 years old bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-13911. Other users have the same problem, for example here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-45244.

This is the recommended solution:

> Please consider using `os.path` for `BASE_DIR`. (...)

I use https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django for my projects, which uses `pathlib` in settings. Even the official Django documentation uses `pathlib`.

That's why I use this hack in `settings` so that PyCharm can autocomplete and I can use `pathlib`:

```py
import os
from pathlib import Path


ROOT_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve(strict=True).parent.parent.parent

# my_project/
APPS_DIR = ROOT_DIR / "my_project"

# STATIC
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-root
STATIC_ROOT = str(ROOT_DIR / "staticfiles")

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#static-url
STATIC_URL = "/static/"

# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/#std:setting-STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    str(APPS_DIR / "static"),
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))), 'my_project', 'static')
]
```

[image: Django staticfiles autocomplete]

Comment: I was able to work around it with a type hint, e.g., `BASE_DIR: os.path.abspath(BASE_DIR)`, where the "real" `BASE_DIR` is still using pathlib.